# ehters JS Event methods

Tags: contract-development, ethers.js, events, event-handling

Is there a difference between calling the event methods with provider.method and calling them with contract.method ?

I could only imagine that contract.method only listens to events from that contract, but for that restriction is the listener itself, isn´t it?